# Is there a way to group rows with a certain name(code) like a list of people living in different states and putting all the TX together and LA togethe

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to group people by the state they are living in. How can I do that using googles app script? I thought of using a forEach loop to group them but im not too sure which direction to go from there.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCn2n.png)

Comment: Why don't you just sort by state.  [Class Range Method Sort](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function sortByState() {
  const sA = ["AL","AK","AS","AZ","AR","CA","CO","CT","DE","DC","FL","GA","GU","HI","ID","IL","IN","IA","KS","KY","LA","ME","MD","MA","MI","MN","MS","MO","MT","NE","NV","NH","NJ","NM","NY","NC","ND","MP","OH","OK","OR","PA","PR","RI","SC","SD","TN","TX","UT","VT","VA","VI","WA","WV","WI","WY"];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const hA = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  let idx = {};
  hA.forEach((h, i) => { idx[h] = i; });
  const rg = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn());
  const vs = rg.getValues().sort((a,b) => {
    vA = sA.indexOf(a[idx['State']]);
    vB = sA.indexOf(b[idx['State']]);
    return vA - vB;
  });
  rg.clearContent();
  sh.getRange(2,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```